# TreeView - Node not expanding

Tags: c#, winforms, treeview, expand, treenode

I have a TreeView with several nodes and if a special node (you will see in code) is deleted, the parent node should be expanded after updating the TreeView.

Here's how I tried it:

```
public void Remove(){
    ...
    ...
    else if ((NodeType)n.Tag == NodeType.Attribute) //Here I simply check if it's the "special" parent
    {
       Commands.CommandAttributeRemove cmd = (Commands.CommandAttributeRemove)mAppData.CommandFactory.Create("AttributeRemove");
       cmd.Data = n.Text;
       cmd.ObjectClass = mObjectClass;
       cmd.ObjectTypeName = n.Parent.Parent.Text;
       list.Add(cmd);
       mNodeToExpand = mTreeView.SelectedNode.Parent; //THIS LINE IS IMPORTANT... mNodeToExpand is a member variable which I use in UpdateData()
    }
    ...
    ...
    UpdateData();
}

public void UpdateData()
    {
       … //A lot of not so important stuff happening here (at least not important for what I want, I think)
       ...
        //Update Selected Items (for the case that objects were deleted) and UpdateSelection
        OnSelect();

        //UpdateSelection();
        this.Update();
```

Now that's interesting stuff:

```
   if (mNodeToExpand != null)
        {
            mNodeToExpand.Expand();
            mNodeToExpand = null;
        }
}
```

This is how I tried to achieve what I want, but the node doesn't expand (it still has other children).

In the `Remove()` I also tried `mTreeView.SelectedNode.Parent.Nodes.Add(new Node("Blabla"));` but it doesn't even add a node.

And in the `if(mNodeToExpand!=null)` I also try to set the selectedNode to mNodeToExpand, but it gives me a NullReferenceException EVEN THOUGH I CHECK IF IT'S NULL IN THE IF. WHY?

Comment: and is mNodeToExpand actually the right node?

Comment: @TaW In the Remove() I set it to the parent of the one which should be removed so theoretically yes

Comment: Well test it by logging out its text before expanding it!

Comment: @TaW I ran through the code with a debugger and it says that mNodeToExpand's Text is "Attributes", which is correct.

Comment: And even when using the debugger it didn't expand?

Comment: @TaW Nope, I didn't see it happening and I ran the debugger in this section line after line

Comment: @TaW I updated the question with another mysterious behaviour. Just have a look at the last sentence

Comment: Ayn code in the Berfore/AfterExpand/Collapse events?

Comment: @TaW Nope, I don't have codes for those events

Comment: You can (for testing) make mNodeToExpand a Property and in the setter log/break to see when it gets set..

Comment: @TaW I don't quite understand what you mean. Could you try to explain it again? Also another info: When I'm in the Remove() and I set mNodeToExpand the attribute FullPath is set to "TopParent//SubParent//NodeToExpand"... But later on in the UpdateData() the full path is only "NodeToExpand"... Could it be that he can't expand it because the FullPath is wrong? Why does this happen?

Comment: I don't know about FullPath. What was unclear? What a Property is? Example:  `TreeNode mNodeToExpand
    {
        get { return mNodeToExpand; }
        set {
                Console.WriteLine(mNodeToExpand.Text + " --> " + value.Text);
                mNodeToExpand = value;
            }
    }`

Comment: @TaW This can't freaking be it. FullPath is apparently the path of the node in the treeview, so for example if you have Node2 which is a sub-node of Node1, then the FullPath of Node1 is "Node1" and of Node2 "Node1//Node2" … Now the thing is that FOR SOME WEIRD REASON my mNodeToExpand loses the Information of FullPath and suddenly it's only "Node2" instead of "Node1//Node2"... Because of that it isn't expanded cause the TreeView doesn't find a node with this FullPath… Now what I did is that I stored the FullPath in a string and when I want to expand it I search for the node with this FullPath

Comment: @TaW and then expand what is returned. This is so stupid, cause imagine a list of 1 000 000 nodes. This could take very long. I'm starting to really dislike this Crownwoods.DotNetMagic library but the company where I'm doing my internship uses it for this window so yeah… Thank you for trying to help me <3

Comment: Um, _Crownwoods.DotNetMagic_ Yu really should have mentioned that you are not using a normal TreeView but one from a library..

Answer (score 0):

This can't freaking be it. FullPath is apparently the path of the node in the treeview, so for example if you have Node2 which is a sub-node of Node1, then the FullPath of Node1 is "Node1" and of Node2 "Node1//Node2" … Now the thing is that FOR SOME WEIRD REASON my mNodeToExpand loses the Information of FullPath and suddenly it's only "Node2" instead of "Node1//Node2"... Because of that it isn't expanded cause the TreeView doesn't find a node with this FullPath… Now what I did is that I stored the FullPath in a string and when I want to expand it I search for the node with this FullPath and then expand what is returned. This is so stupid, cause imagine a list of 1 000 000 nodes. This could take very long. I'm starting to really dislike this Crownwoods.DotNetMagic library but it's already existing Code I'm working on.